# Vue 2 child and parent two way sync

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is my custom wrapper around vue-multiselect package. it is the child in this question.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <multiselect
            v-model="items"
            :options="filteredList"
            :multiple="multiple"
            :close-on-select="multiple ? false : true"
            :show-labels="false"
            :placeholder="placeholder"
            track-by="id"
            :label="label"
            @input="inputChanged"
            :internal-search="false"
            @search-change="searchItems"
        >
        </multiselect>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        model: {
            prop: 'parentItems',
            event: 'change',
        },
        props: ['multiple', 'list', 'placeholder', 'label', 'parentItems'],
        data() {
            return {
                items: this.parentItems,
                filteredList: this.list,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            searchItems(query) {
                let q = latinize(query.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,''))
                this.filteredList = this.list.filter(li => latinize(li[this.label].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'')).includes(q))
            },
            inputChanged() {
                this.$emit('change', this.items)
                this.$emit('filters-changed')
            },
            resetItems() {
                this.items = this.multiple ? [] : null
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

parent element looks like this

```
<custom-multiselect
    v-model="car"
    :multiple="false"
    :list="cars"
    placeholder="Car"
    label="pseudo_id_name"
></custom-multiselect>
```

I either want to not use `items`, I'd rather only use `parentItems`, which of course, results in this warning

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value
will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.
Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "parentItems"
```

what counts as parent component re-render? in all my tests, it solved the two way sync and did not break anything. if using the prop as data was viable in my case, is there something i can do to suppress this warning?

if it is still wrong, i'd like to know how to make items synchronized. i read many stackoverflow questions/answers on this topic, but still don't fully undestand.

now with my v-model i `$emit` changes to the parent, which work just fine. i struggle with the other way around.

when on my parent element i call `resetForm()`, which sets `this.car = null`, child does not know that `items` should also become null. how do i listen for this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this to the child element seems to work. however, if there is a cleaner way, please let me know.

```
watch: {
    parentItems: function (val, oldVal) {
        this.items = this.parentItems
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make items a computed prop with a getter and setter method, and bind it to your child component's model with v-model="items". This will work well as long as parentItems is a required prop, which means it is always passed to your custom component. If parentItems would be an optional prop I'd stick with your solution of keeping a copy of that prop in data (and coming up with a good default value), and emitting the change event in a watcher.

```
computed: {
  items:{
    get(){
      return this.parentItems;
    },
    set(value){
      this.$emit('change', value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks good, but i think i need a variable in data because of how vue-multiselect works. it has to have a v-model property on itself.